# Is Dirichlet energy related with entropy?

Tags: functional-analysis, harmonic-analysis, entropy

Intuitively, I feel that Dirichlet energy is related with entropy. And entropy seems to be equivalent with some discrete form of Dirichlet energy.

Is this a nice intuition?

Is there something worth discussing here?

Comment: Could you elaborate why you think this is the case?

Comment: @almosteverywhere The solve of Laplacian equation is the minimum case of Dirichlet energy, which means the final equilibrium of a thermal diffusion, which also means the entropy is maximized.

Answer (score 0):

There is a loose relationship I would say. Consider the thermal diffusion you mentioned in your comment, i.e. the heat equation on $\mathbb{T}^d$ (for simplicity),
\begin{align}
\partial_t \rho = \Delta \rho\\
\rho(0)=\rho_0 \, ,
\end{align}
where $\rho_0$ is a Borel probability measure on $\mathbb{T}^d$. There are two ways of interpreting this equation: it is gradient flow of the Dirichlet energy with respect to the $L^2$ metric or it is gradient flow of the entropy with respect to the $2$-Wasserstein metric on the space of probability measures (see this paper by Jordan, Kinderlehrer, and Otto: https://francahoffmann.files.wordpress.com/2018/07/302ca7465ae824f3d2d629bfeaacfb56b4b8.pdf ). Both quantities measure, in some sense, how far you are from the constant and they are both zero when $\rho$ is constant.

Comment: Yes, the question is how are the two measures related quantitatively. Dirichlet energy quantifies how variable the distribution function is, which is so close to the micro-scale definition of entropy. So this is why I feel entropy is like a discrete version of Dirichlet energy.

Comment: Also, in computer vision, an image with higher Dirichlet energy should be viewed with more information, which is also related with entropy. I think the result of derivation will be useful.